# What are the advantages from using as and then comparing with null over is and a direct cast?

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
var someObject = GetSomeObject as ISomeInterface;    
if (someObject != null)
{ 
  // do someting, not only one method call with this object, so don't expect null propagation to be handy
  someObject.CallSomeMethod();
}
```

Is that preferable over this:?

```
var someObject = GetSomeObject();
if (someObject is ISomeInterface)
{ 
  // do someting
  ((ISomeInterface)someObject).CallSomeMethod();
}
```

What are the differences and when would I chose what to use?

Is it just about readability?

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe but I'm on my phone right now so can't really look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes more sense when you have more than one call.
If you need to call multiple methods, then in case 2 you will have to either:

1. Cast it 3 times

   ```
   var someObject = GetSomeObject();
   if (someObject is ISomeInterface)
   { 
     ((ISomeInterface)someObject).CallSomeMethod1();
     ((ISomeInterface)someObject).CallSomeMethod2();
     ((ISomeInterface)someObject).CallSomeMethod3();
   }
   ```
2. Declare a new casted object:

   ```
   var someObject = GetSomeObject();
   if (someObject is ISomeInterface)
   { 
     var someObjectCasted = (ISomeInterface)someObject;
     someObjectCasted.CallSomeMethod1();
     someObjectCasted.CallSomeMethod2();
     someObjectCasted.CallSomeMethod3();
   }
   ```

Both methods do definitely not improve code readability.

Answer (score -1):

Overall, I think that when you have to explicitly cast an object to a certain type, you have to already look at your code because casting is bad practice. So I would prefer the first example.

Comment: "_casting is bad practice_" how comes so?

Comment: Explicitly casting often is the cause of poor design choices in the program. It raises questions. "Why? If you really want something to be a particular type, why didn't you define it to be that type to start with?" Unless there is a specific reason you need to cast it, I would define it as a certain type, and make sure it stays that type until I have a reason to change it. But this is just my opinion, and you're free to choose.

Comment: You confuse causation and correlation - lots of casting can be caused by poor design and can be a indication of it, but casting itself isn't bad at all.

Comment: I would edit my original post by saying that casting without any legitimate reason is bad practice. If you have a reason, I can accept that.